# Change in file does not trigger reload of Node server

Tags: node.js

> Windows 10, VS Code, Node 10.16.2.

I have a small project that only contains a few files - index.js and a css file mainly.

`npm start` starts the project and a message says `Server will reload automatically if you modify any file!`

This works if I modify the css file for example. But if I modify the `index.js` file nothing happens.

My Node setup is default. I have not manually installed any modules to watch for file changes and I don't want to. Just trying to figure out why this doesn't work for the js file.

> EDIT

Below is the contents of `package.json`. Something else interesting is that if I allow `index.js` to be linted I get a weird error about the equals sign after `propTypes`. Someone suggested might be an issue with `webpack`, which I know nothing about. But they said if the file won't build because of an error then a change in the file might not be detected. Note, though, that the project runs fine.

```
static propTypes = {
    width: PropTypes.number,
    height: PropTypes.number
};
```

Here is package.json:

```
{
"private": true,
"name": "some name",
"description": "some description",
"version": "0.1.0",
"scripts": {
    "start": "nr1 package:serve",
    "test": "exit 0"
},
"nr1": {
    "uuid": "e13bf28f-8989-4a3a-832c-7c3f0eec6c3e",
    "sdkVersion": 2
},
"dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
},
"browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie < 11",
    "not dead"
],
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3"
}
```

}

Comment: can you please add contents of your `package.json` file so we can see the start and build commands for your app?  i actually didn't know that node restarts on code change without something like nodemon.

Comment: did u install nodemon and added it to package.json where npm start will trigger the nodemon ?

Comment: node doesn't but if you have an ide configured to automatic reload maybe that it will be the case. I am wondering where the message it is coming from though

Comment: See edits to original post.